# grails - returning Object or id from formRemote

Tags: javascript, forms, grails

I have a grails app where, after a user enters a name for a new domain object (Sync), I want to save the object, move to a fragment on the same page, and change the css class of a div (to js colorbox, if that matters).

To do this, I use an anchor to set the class and move to the fragment and use JS to submit a g:formRemote. However, the formRemote does not return the created object.

partial of gsp:

```
<g:formRemote url="[controller: 'Main', action:'createNewSync']" name="newSyncForm"   >
<g:field type="text" name="newSyncName" />

<a id="ns-link" href="#outline_content" class="outline">
<script>
  $('#ns-link').click(function(){
     $('#newSyncForm').submit();
  });
 </script>
 </g:formRemote>
```

Later in the gsp, we want to move to use the colorbox with the outline_content inside. Notice the syncInstance.name is needed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".outline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"1140px", escKey:false, overlayClose:false});
</script>

<div id="sync" class="hidden">
<div id='outline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;' >
    <h2 class="nameheader"><strong style="color:#000;">New Sync:</strong><span class="editable_textile">${syncInstance?.name}</span></h2>
        <div class="number1"><img src="../images/1.png" border="0" /></div>
```

.....

controller:

```
def createNewSync(){
    params.name = params.newSyncName
    def syncInstance =  Sync?.findByName(params.newSyncName) 

if (!syncInstance)
{
        syncInstance = new Sync(params)
        def u = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal)
        syncInstance.properties['createdBy'] = u
        syncInstance.properties['createdDate'] = new Date().toString()
        syncInstance.properties['lastRunTime'] = "Never"
        syncInstance.properties['lastRunOutcome'] = "---"
        syncInstance.properties['isScheduled'] = false
        syncInstance.properties['isComplete'] = false

        syncInstance.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

    }        
    //doesn't send anything back to page if it's been called remotely
    [syncInstance: syncInstance]
}
```

Is there any way to get a reference to the created object to be used later on the page using this method? If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you update your post to have more detail? What is the domain class you want to return? What part of it do you want displayed on the page and where? Also show the controller you are using.

Comment: @JamesKleeh updated with requested code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is what I would do

1) Create a template for the sync. It would be everything contained inside the div with the id of "sync", but not the div itself.

2) Update your formRemote tag to update that div  `<g:formRemote update="sync" ... />`

3) Render the template in your controller  `render(template: "path/to/template", model:[syncInstance: syncInstance])`